# MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock;

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I have a table trade_order:

```
 CREATE TABLE `trade_order` IF NOT EXISTS `buyer_order` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `order_no` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `name` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `order_no` (`order_no`),
 )
```

Now I want to insert data into table trade_order. I do it like this:

```
transaction begin.
===
result = select * from order_table where order_no = #{orderNo} for update 
if(result is null){
    insert into trade_order (order_no,name) values (orderNo,name)
}
else{
    update trade_order set name = #{name} where order_no = #{orderNo}
}
===
transaction end.
```

But I got deadLock exeption:

```
 org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException: 
 ### Error updating database.  Cause:      com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock      found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
 ### The error may involve      com.youzan.trade.process.datasync.dal.dao.OrderDAO.insert-Inline
 ### The error occurred while setting parameters
 ### SQL: insert into trade_order ( order_no, name )  values ( ?,         ?,  )
 ### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
 ; SQL []; Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Maybe the same two data would be deal with by two threads at the same time,and the two threads both do insert action.

But will it be result in deadLock?I wonder why.

(The mysql transaction isolate level is RR, InnoDB engine)

Comment: It seems that the query and the insert are not in the same transaction. I see that you are using a dao framework. Are you sure that all operations are using the same transaction? If you remove the for update from the query?

Comment: Can you retrieve more information about deadlock with one of the method explained here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks.html?

Comment: Here there's an interesting explanation about having unexpected deadlock during a simple insert. The problem seems related to the presence of a primary key with autoincrement and a unique ley like your table: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86878/mysql-innodb-deadlock-for-2-simple-insert-queries

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but maybe somebody finds it useful.

The cause might be that MySQL's InnoDB uses insert intention locks which lock a set of rows when inserting or updating.

Check [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking.html) for more information about the different types of locks that InnoDB uses.

[This link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html) explains a bit about the deadlocks.

Sometimes it will be almost impossible to prevent these deadlocks. The most common solutions are:

1. The first option is always operate in the tables in the same order
2. Reduce the scope (duration) of the transaction to the minimum
3. If necessary, lock in advance (already done automatically for your case)
4. Retry the transaction